# Who are the people Cain was afraid of that would slay him?

Tags: genesis

> Behold, you have driven me today away from the ground, and from your face I shall be hidden. I shall be a fugitive and a wanderer on the earth, and **whoever finds me** will kill me.
>   -- Genesis 4:14 (ESV)

In Gen 4, the only children Adam and Eve had were Cain and Abel, yet in this verse Cain was afraid that everyone who finds him would slay him. Who are the people that Cain was afraid would slay him?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that this is further indication that Adam and Eve probably had many other children, although this is not explicitely stated here. The emphasis on Seth was because he was viewed as a replacement for Abel. Although in 4:17 it is stated that Cain had a wife, we cannot be certain of the chronological development of this chapter.

Comment: +1 Although it isn't explicitly stated here, Genesis 5:2 indicates that Adam indeed had several other children as you suggest, because it states that he begat "sons and daughters," even though none of the daughters are mentioned by name.